# text to decimal C

Tags: c, ascii

Manual conversion.

For example, input = axe, why the dec of 'a' (97) always in endless loop?

Can't move to 'x' dec and 'e'?

```
//project text to ASCII Dec
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    char i=0, data, a;

    printf("Enter data : ");
    scanf("%s", &data); //or %c

    while(data != i){ /* can't out from this loop I mean to the next letter of word */
      a = data;
      printf("%d", data); // or printf("%d", a);
      if(data != 0){
        printf("-");
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: input and expected output please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared `data` as type `char`, meaning it can only hold a *single* character value (`'A'`', `'1'`, `'0'`, `'\n'`, etc. ).

If you want to be able to store a *string* to `data` (such as `"axe"` or `"foo"` or `"Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious"`), then you will need to declare `data` as an *array* of `char`, and the array size must be at least one longer than the length of the longest string you intend to store:

```
#define STRING_LENGTH 20 // store strings *up to* 20 characters long
...
char data[STRING_LENGTH + 1]; // +1 for the 0 terminator that marks
                              // the end of the string
```

As for the endless loop, `'a'` (97) is never equal to `i` (0), and you never update the value of either entity in the loop.  You have to update one or the other each time through the loop.  Here's what I *think* you're going for:

```
if ( fgets( data, sizeof data, stdin ) ) // safer than using scanf
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; data[i] != 0; i++ )
  {
    printf( "%d ", data[i] ); // print out character encoding value
  }
}
```

This code takes a string input by the user and prints the encoding value of each character (ASCII, EBCDIC, UTF-8, whatever) as an integer.

Comment: I can't find `"Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious"` in Webster's or Oxford's? Poppins' maybe?

Comment: 'for' loop is error C99 whatever, after that, i try to delete 'size_t' and it works

Comment: @TegarBangunSuganda: Sorry, used to working in C99 and later.  For C89 and earlier, you'd have to declare `i` outside of the loop.